# HammerJS pan fails for grandchild element in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, hammer.js

I have a [gallery pen](https://codepen.io/seanbischoff/pen/aYYoMy) (based on a [pen by Drew Power](https://codepen.io/dangodev/pen/bpjrRg)) with Hammerjs Pan to slide images horizontally. Works fine in Chrome & Safari, but not in Firefox

The basic structure:

```
<div class="slider">
    <picture><img></picture>
    <picture><img></picture>
    <picture><img></picture>
</div>
```

- div.slider is the Hammer.Manager instance el, with a "pan" listener.
- there will also be accompanying source tags for each img

In Firefox, with left/right margins on the img exposing some of the parent picture element, clicking on the parent to start the pan works. But clicking on it's child element the img does not work. The pan listener hears the event and starts the pan, but it immediately ends.

Use of CSS touch-action:none and -webkit-user-drag:none on  makes no difference.

**Removing the img tag and using it as background of a div instead is not desirable**, as we lose the benefits of responsive image sizes we get from using the picture+source+img tags.

Here is a pen of the issue
https://codepen.io/seanbischoff/details/aYYoMy/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Add `draggable='false'` and `ondragstart='return false'` attributes. It would prevent dragging in FF.

```
<img src="..." draggable='false' ondragstart='return false'>
```

[Modified CodePen](https://codepen.io/shitpoet/pen/PdBMwW)

Comment: This helped me get the pan behavior working for me at all using Hammer.js v2.0.8 and firefox 63.0.3. Many thanks.